# Theme like Admin Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, admin, drupal-themes

I want a theme for Drupal like this:
http://themeforest.net/item/webpro-admin-dashboard-template/7372284

But this template does not help me because only have HTML files, not is a Drupal's theme easy for install.

Anyone know how to install it or there is another similar theme?

Answer (score 1):

Try Adminimal. It's pretty close to your criteria : [Adminimal Theme official link](https://drupal.org/project/adminimal_theme)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you get an out of the box drupal theme the only way is for you (or someone else if you are willing to pay someone) to create a drupal theme based on that theme.

You can likely reuse a lof of the markup and css from the theme you like but there will still be a lot of work to make a drupal theme from it.

As for other similar themes, I don't know. There possibly are, you'll just have to look around. Stack overflow isn't really for theme suggestions, it's for programming questions.

Comment: Yes, I expected that :(. I downloaded the theme Bootstrap 3 and I'm starting to modify it. Thxs.